# Почему глобальный объект $_POST пустой после отправки формы?

Tags: php, mysql

Такая проблема, хочу загрузить видео на сервер через input type=file. Делаю следующее :

```
<form action="controllers/Video/add-video.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="upload-video__content">
                                <div class="upload-video__content-block">
                                    <label>Выберите видеозапись: </label>
                                    <input required type="file" name="video">
                                </div>
                                <div class="upload-video__footer text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" name="upload_video_sub">Загрузить</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

и соответственно пхп контролер:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once "../../db/db.php";
    $user_email = $_SESSION['user_login'];
    $get_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user_email'";
    $user = mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query($get_user));
    $user_id = $user['id'];

    if (isset($_POST['upload_video_sub'])) {
        if (!empty($_FILES['video']['name'])) {
            if (!empty($_FILES['video']['error'])) die('Ошибка загрузки видео. <a href="../../videos.php">Попробуйте еще раз.</a>');

            #if user picture has size more tham 200MB
            //if ($_FILES['video']['size'] > 200 * 1024 * 1024) die('Похоже вы загружаете слижком большое по размеру видео. <a href="../../videos.php">Попробуйте выбрать другой файл.</a>');

            $original_file_name = $_FILES['video']['name'];  //user file name
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];  //user photo
            $extension = pathinfo($original_file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  //get extention of photo
            $file_name = md5(uniqid(rand(),1)) . '.' . $extension;  //generate new name 

            //if user dont have own media folder
            if (empty($user['user_folder'])) {
                $user_folder = 'user_' . md5(uniqid(rand(), 1));  //generate unique name for users folder
                mkdir('../../users-media/' . $user_folder);  //create necessary folders
                if (!file_exists('../../users-media/' . $user_folder . '/videos'))
                    mkdir('../../users-media/' . $user_folder . '/videos');
                $path = '../../users-media/' . $user_folder . '/videos/';  //generate path
                $set_users_folder = "UPDATE users SET user_folder='$user_folder' WHERE id='$user_id'";
                mysqli_query($conn, $set_users_folder) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            } else { 
                //if user already have media folder
                $user_folder = $user['user_folder'];
                if (!file_exists('../../users-media/' . $user_folder . '/videos'))
                    mkdir('../../users-media/' . $user_folder . '/videos');
                $path = '../../users-media/' . $user_folder . '/videos/'; 
            }

            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path . $file_name)) {
                $upload_video = "INSERT INTO videos (user_id, user_video) VALUES ('$user_id', '$file_name')";
                mysqli_query($conn, $upload_video) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                header('Location: /dev/videos.php');
            } else { die('Ошибка загрузки видео. <a href="../../videos.php">Попробуйте еще раз.</a>'); }
        }
    } else { die('Ошибка загрузки видео3. <a href="../../videos.php">Попробуйте еще раз.</a>'); }
?>
```

При попытке загрузить видео выдается "Ошибка загрузки видео3.", а это значит что if (isset($_POST['upload_video_sub'])) не сработал. Но почему он не сработал если имена совпадают и в кнопке стоит type=submit? Даже если я сделаю еще несколько инпутов, то при ПОСТ запросе глобальный объект все равно будет пустым

Answer (score 0):

if (isset($_POST['upload_video_sub'])) - эта проверка не выполняется, так как upload_video_sub - это кнопка отправки формы. Не уверен, но её значение пустое должно быть

Comment: Прикол в том что даже когда я эту проверку уберу у меня все равно не выполнится следующее условие if (!empty($_FILES['video']['name'])) хотя файл я выбрал и оно должно сюда зайти

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте что котроллер получает данные

```
print "<hr><pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($HTTP_POST_VARS);
print "</pre>";
```

В тестах все работает

Comment: array(0) {
}
NULL
вот что получаю, при выводе $_POST и $_FILEs

Comment: Не понимаю почему так, делал аналогично загрузку фотографий, там все работало

Comment: Чистый php или framework?

Comment: чистый................

Comment: В браузере с включенной отладкой видно что данные уходят? Выложи весь код html